# I want to use AUPRC as the performance measure, in a GBM run using caret package. How can I use a customized metric such as auprc?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to use AUPRC as my custom metric for a gbm model fit because I have imbalanced classifier. However, when i try to incorporate the custom metric I am getting the following error mentioned in the code. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Also the auprcSummary() works on its own when i run it inline. It is giving me an error when i try to incorporate it in train().

```
     library(dplyr) # for data manipulation
     library(caret) # for model-building
     library(pROC) # for AUC calculations
     library(PRROC) # for Precision-Recall curve calculations

    auprcSummary <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL){
      index_class2 <- data$Class == "Class2"
      index_class1 <- data$Class == "Class1"
      the_curve <- pr.curve(data$Class[index_class2],
                    data$Class[index_class1],
                    curve = FALSE)
      out <- the_curve$auc.integral
      names(out) <- "AUPRC"
      out
      }

    ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                 number = 10,
                 repeats = 5,
                 summaryFunction = auprcSummary,
                 classProbs = TRUE)

    set.seed(5627)
    orig_fit <- train(Class ~ .,
              data = toanalyze.train,
              method = "gbm",
              verbose = FALSE,
              metric = "AUPRC",
              trControl = ctrl)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
     Error in order(scores.class0) : argument 1 is not a vector
```

Is it because pr.curve() takes only numeric vectors as inputs (scores/probabilities?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach yields an appropriate custom summary function:

```
library(caret) 
library(pROC) 
library(PRROC)
library(mlbench) #for the data set

data(Ionosphere)
```

in `pr.curve` function the classification scores may be either provided separately for the data points of each of the classes, i.e., as `scores.class0` for the data points from the positive/foreground class and as `scores.class1` for the data points of the negative/background class; or the classification scores for all data points are provided as `scores.class0` and the labels are provided as numerical values (1 for the positive class, 0 for the negative class) as `weights.class0` (I copied this from the help of the function I apologize if it is unclear).

I opted to provide the later - probability for all in `scores.class0`  and class assignment in `weights.class0`.

caret states that  if the classProbs argument of the trainControl object is set to TRUE, additional columns in data will be present that contains the class probabilities. So for the `Ionosphere` data columns `good` and `bad` should be present:

```
levels(Ionosphere$Class)
#output
[1] "bad"  "good"
```

to convert to 0/1 labeling one can just do:

```
as.numeric(Ionosphere$Class) - 1
```

`good` will become `1`
`bad` will become `0`

now we have all the data for the custom function

```
auprcSummary <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL){
  prob_good <- data$good #take the probability of good class
  the_curve <- pr.curve(scores.class0 = prob_good,
                        weights.class0 = as.numeric(data$obs)-1, #provide the class labels as 0/1
                        curve = FALSE)
  out <- the_curve$auc.integral
  names(out) <- "AUPRC"
  out
}
```

Instead of using `data$good` which will work on this data set alone one can extract the class names and use that to get the desired column:

```
  lvls <- levels(data$obs)
  prob_good <- data[,lvls[2]]
```

It is important to note each time you update the summaryFunction you need to update the trainControl object.

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                     number = 10,
                     repeats = 5,
                     summaryFunction = auprcSummary,
                     classProbs = TRUE)

orig_fit <- train(y = Ionosphere$Class, x = Ionosphere[,c(1,3:34)], #omit column 2 to avoid a bunch of warnings related to the data set
                  method = "gbm",
                  verbose = FALSE,
                  metric = "AUPRC",
                  trControl = ctrl)

orig_fit$results
#output
  shrinkage interaction.depth n.minobsinnode n.trees     AUPRC    AUPRCSD
1       0.1                 1             10      50 0.9722775 0.03524882
4       0.1                 2             10      50 0.9758017 0.03143379
7       0.1                 3             10      50 0.9739880 0.03316923
2       0.1                 1             10     100 0.9786706 0.02502183
5       0.1                 2             10     100 0.9817447 0.02276883
8       0.1                 3             10     100 0.9772322 0.03301064
3       0.1                 1             10     150 0.9809693 0.02078601
6       0.1                 2             10     150 0.9824430 0.02284361
9       0.1                 3             10     150 0.9818318 0.02287886
```

Seems reasonable

Answer (score 2):

`caret` has a built-in function called `prSummary` that computes that for you. You don't have to write your own.